# javascript two button change each other using single function

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick

I've following code to change value inside one button by clicking another and vice-versa. Here, I used two function and two variables... what I want is to use single function and single variable.

```js
        i=1;
  j=1;
  function changeSecond(){
   if(i==1){
    document.getElementById('second').innerHTML='second changed';
    i++;
   }else{
     document.getElementById('second').innerHTML='Second Button';
     i--;
    }
  }
  function changeFirst(){
   if(j==1){// use 'i' here instead j ... 
    document.getElementById('first').innerHTML='First changed';
    j++;
   }else{
     document.getElementById('first').innerHTML='First Button';
     j--;
    }
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="changeSecond();" id="first">First Button</button>
<button onclick="changeFirst();" id="second">Second Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single function and no variable like

```js
function changeme(id) {
  var other = document.getElementById(id == 'first' ? 'second' : 'first');
  if (/changed/i.test(other.innerHTML)) {
    other.innerHTML = other.innerHTML.replace('Changed', 'Button');
  } else {
    other.innerHTML = other.innerHTML.replace('Button', 'Changed');
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeme(this.id);" id="first">First Button</button>
<button onclick="changeme(this.id);" id="second">Second Button</button>
```

---

If you want to store the state in a variable then

```js
var value = 0;

function changeme(id) {
  var other = document.getElementById(id == 'first' ? 'second' : 'first'),
    val = id == 'first' ? 1 : 2;

  if (value & val) {
    other.innerHTML = other.innerHTML.replace('Changed', 'Button');
    value ^= val;
  } else {
    other.innerHTML = other.innerHTML.replace('Button', 'Changed');
    value |= val;
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="changeme(this.id);" id="first">First Button</button>
<button onclick="changeme(this.id);" id="second">Second Button</button>
```

Comment: Excellent answer!  I just learned something new.  Can you explain what the line `if (/changed/i.test(other.innerHTML)) {` is doing in the first solution?

Comment: @Christian that is a regular expression to check whether the html contains the text changed... if so we need to replace the changed with button

Comment: Thank you Arun Sir. It helped me lot